# Getting nulls when deserializing XML data

Tags: c#, xml

Trying to deserialise the following:

```
<ArrayOfServiceQualificationResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ServiceQualificationResponse>
    <status_code>1</status_code>
    <property_id>123</property_id>
    <unit_no>1</unit_no>
    <house_no>11</house_no>
    <lot_no>1</lot_no>
    <street_name>Test</street_name>
    <street_type>Lane</street_type>
    <suburb>Test Suburb</suburb>
    <state_name>NSW</state_name>
    <postcode>2008</postcode>
    <estate_name>Test Estate</estate_name>
    <stage>Test Stage</stage>
    <property_class>Test Class</property_class>
  </ServiceQualificationResponse>
</ArrayOfServiceQualificationResponse>
```

using the code below:

```
 var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfServiceQualificationResponse));
                    using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
                    {
                        ArrayOfServiceQualificationResponse obj;
                        obj = (ArrayOfServiceQualificationResponse)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                        xmlReader.Close();
                        return obj;
                    }
```

The object generated has null values for every field. I don't understand why.

The ArrayOfServiceQualificationResponse and ServiceQualificationResponse  are auto-generated as following:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="ArrayOfServiceQualificationResponse", Namespace= "http://tempuri.org/", ItemName="ResponseItem")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class ArrayOfServiceQualificationResponse : System.Collections.Generic.List<Primus.Opticomm.Gateway.ExternalProxy.OpticommB2BService.ServiceQualificationResponse> {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ServiceQualificationResponse", Namespace= "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class ServiceQualificationResponse : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. It's not really possible guess. I would note you're using `XmlSerializer` but your classes appear to have attributes for `DataContractSerializer`. And the namespaces don't match your XML.

Comment: You are inheriting classes which adds a type attribute to the xml data.  Without the type in the xml file you will not get any data.  I recommend creating a test classes with data and using Serialize to create an XML file to see the missing attributes.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will investigate by creating test classes and then Serializing/deserializing